What's the original source "Erst am Ende unseres Weges stehen die Antworten."
In a museum I saw a drawing with text:

Erst am Ende unseres Weges stehen die Antworten.

I guess the meaning is "The answer lays in the end of our way".
When I search it in internet, this is the name of a book, which should be sayings of an old Chinese, founder of Taoism, Laotse.  And some said this is the saying of Laotse.
It surprised me somehow, I am a Chinese and had read this only book of Laotse, I remember some part of the book but don't know which one is translated into this sentence.
I find the book and read it again, still can not find any sentence relate to it.
There is another sentence in Chinese, it's not said by Laotse, but Konfuzius which has similar meanings. In Chinese "朝闻道 夕死可矣", which means "There would be no regret if you know the truth in the morning and dead in the evening". It was translate to Germany as "In der Frühe die Wahrheit vernehmen und des Abends sterben, das ist nicht schlimm.".  There was a story, Konfuzius asked Laotse about "Truth(Way)", but did not understand it until asked 3rd time when he is very old, then he said this sentence.
Could someone help me figure out from which sentence is this text translated?
Added:

It's MMM (Messner Mountain Museum) Ripa in Bruneck Italy.
Shared photo of the totem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AiMd5hbE0j7cLnPtVeDcuRNN99-rJX3y/view?usp=drive_link

The only book of Laotse is "道德经" in Chinese, in Germany "Das buch vom Sinn und Leben".  I found a germany website contain many translations include this one, and match some of them to Chinese, but not this one.  https://www.sprichworte-der-welt.de/chinesische_sprichworte/laotse.html

Another interesting thing is there are 107 different translations and publish of the book in Germany.



I can't say about the translation from Chinese to German, but the German sentence translated to English would be: "The answers are only at the end of our way."

What is the museum, the artist and the name of the drawing? How shall we know without further information?

I'd translate it as "...end of our path"

As stated in the question, there is a German book with the title
"Erst am Ende unseres Weges stehen die Antworten: Sinnsprüche von Laotse und Dschuang Dsi" (The answers only come at the end of our journey: Aphorisms by Laotse and Zhuang Zhou).
I do not have access to this book, but I guess it attributes the sentence to Laotse. In the internet you can also find a few other collections of quotations and aphorisms which definitely attribute it to Laotse, for example here.
However, I recommend to be cautious concerning aphorisms, even if they are contained in books (which seems to "ennoble" them to indisputable truths).
It is of course very well possible that Laotse or Zhuang Zhou wrote it, but this can only be answered by somebody who is familiar with their books. But it is also possible that it is a fake quotation which spread around by copying it over the course of time.
Here is another question of a similar spirit: What is the original German version of Bismarck's phrase about intentions and capabilities? It asks for the German original of an aphorism which is popular in Russia and is attributed to Otto von Bismarck. It does not seem to exist in German, probably it is a counterfeit. In an answer to this question I made a digression concerning the attribution of "quotations" using as an example a fake quotation by Confucius.

@bakunin The question is "From which sentence is this text translated?" One could also argue that the whole question is off topic because it can only be answered by a person knowing  the orginal Chinese texts. Nevertheless I think the question is interesting and that the answer contains an interesting hypothesis.

Some valid translations of the German sentence into English are:


The answers are only at the end of our way.
The answers only come at the end of our journey.


#1 is more literal, #2 better covers the meaning of the sentence.
Without any knowledge of Chinese, I post here some translations of this sentence, that the translation software DeepL gave me. I hope that one of them will help you to find what you are looking for:


答案只会在我们旅程的终点出现。
答案只有在我们的旅程结束时才会出现。
答案只有在我们旅程的终点才会出现。
答案只有在我们的旅程结束时才能找到。
答案就在我们前行的尽头。
答案只在我们前行的尽头。
答案就在我们前行的终点。
答案就在我们前行的终点。


I also found a book with that sentence as title:

Erst am Ende unseres Weges stehen die Antworten.
Sinnsprüche von Laotse und Dschuang Dsi
Walter Fehlinger (Herausgeber)

There is a German website with Aphorisms, and it has a page about this sentence: https://www.aphorismen.de/zitat/184977 and there the author of this page wrote, that it's from Laotse.
